# Spring | SPEL multiple property accessors

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I'm trying to use SPeL with multiple property accessors.

```
StandardEvaluationContext simpleContext = new StandardEvaluationContext(myPojo);
        simpleContext.setVariable("ctx", ruleExecutionContext);
        simpleContext.setPropertyAccessors(Arrays.asList(new MapAccessor(), new ReflectivePropertyAccessor()));
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        return (Boolean) parser.parseExpression(spelExpression).getValue(simpleContext, RulebaseConfiguration.LIB_MAP);
```

RulebaseConfiguration.LIB_MAP contains `{"instanceName": instance}`

I want to pass expressions that could operate on a POJO as well as call methods on the instance. But it only takes map into the effect.

I get this error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'payload' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.HashMap' - maybe not public?] with root cause
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'payload' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.HashMap' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:226)
```

Comment: You need to show your expression and exactly what you are trying to do. `getValue(ctx, rootObject)` overrides the `rootObject` passed into the context's ctor.

Comment: Expression: `payload['nationality'] == 'GBR'` MyPojo (root object) has a map called payload.

Comment: In a few other cases, I will also have an expression like this: `payload['channel'] == nationalityLookup.resolveChannel('CBR1000')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Creating a context and parsing the expression for each request is wasteful, unless it's different for each request; in which case, consider caching expressions/contexts.
2. As I said, since you are passing a `rootObject` to `getValue()`, your `myPojo` is "hidden" - the evaluation is always performed on `LIB_MAP`.

You need to call `getValue()` without a root object to use the context's root object. You can add `LIB_MAP` as a variable (e.g. with name `nationalityLookup`) and use

```
payload['channel'] == #nationalityLookup.resolveChannel('CBR1000')
```